# Offline Firestore Image Upload Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-storage

I am building a record entry application that requires text input and image. The application uses Firebase Firestore and has offline capabilities turned on. The problem I am facing now is when the device is offline, the image captured from the camera doesn't get uploaded after the data has been stored on Firestore. Below is my code.

```
Future<void> uploadImage(Record data) async {
    isLoading(true);
    Reference refRoot = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    Reference ref = refRoot.child(data.uuid);
    var url = '';
    try {
      CollectionReference refCol =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('data');
      refCol.doc(data.uuid).set(
        {
          "phone_no": data.phoneNo,
          "gender": data.gender,
          "image_url": url,
          "middle_name": data.middleName,
          "surname": data.surname,
        },
      ).then((value) => {
            ref.putFile(File(filePath.value.toString())),
            url = ref.getDownloadURL() as String,
            refCol.doc(data.uuid).set(
              {
                "image_url": url,
              },
            )
          });
      isLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

When the application is turned back online, the record is uploaded but the image doesn't get uploaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're uploading an image to Cloud Storage through Firebase, **not** to Firestore. `Reference refRoot = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    Reference ref = refRoot.child(data.uuid);`

Comment: How did you determine that the image doesn't get uploaded? Note that both `putFile` and `getDownloadURL` are asynchronous calls, so either need `then` or `await` to get their results.

Comment: Yea, I am uploading the image to storage and then storing the image URL in Firestore. When the device is online.

Comment: When the device is online, everything works fine. But when offline, the data uploads and doesn't upload the image, hence the image URL is empty.